# Do I need to do anything different with the client or is it a server setting that needs modification?

Tags: apache-flex, api, http, flash-media-server

I have a Flex based application which is using Flash Media Server (FMS) server (version 4.0)  for live video streaming between two users (i.e. a one to one teleconferencing service). This streaming is one-to-one, as defined by business rules, so that no third person can join a teleconference. Either person can start the video stream via a browser-based Flex client and communication gets established once the second user joins. Validation for connecting the streams of the two users is implemented on the FMS server (as server side scripting defined in main.asc). I am facing three critical problems with our teleconferencing solution.

1.Often times, full communication can not be established between the two users. One user can not usually see or hear the other user. There is a client side 'refresh' button that when clicked, attempts to establish a connection via the server side script. This sometimes works. Before implementing our current server side script, I tried establishing a stream by using methods found here: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/905613

I think the method below may work as it would give me an array of subscribers to the stream.

getLiveStreamStats(appInst:String, stream:String) : Object

But the problem is that server returns the following:

```
<level>error</level>
<code>Admin.API.MethodNotAllowed</code>
<description>getlivestreams - Method not allowed!</description>
<timestamp>8/7/2012 10:05:38 AM</timestamp>
```

Question - Do I need to do anything different with the client or is it a server setting that needs modification?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify if you were making the remote calls using HTTP or RMTP. If you're using RMTP you shouldn't have to do anything. If you're using HTTP you will need to modify the following files:

- {Flash/Adobe Media Server Root}\conf\AMS.ini (or FMS.ini if you're on an older version)
- {Flash/Adobe Media Server Root}\conf\Users.xml

In the first, you will need to set the USERS.HTTPCOMMAND_ALLOW option to true. In my version of the AMS.ini file it is at the very bottom of the configuration page.

In the Users.xml file, you will need to locate the  block. In my version, this is also located towards the bottom of the page. The default install of Adobe Media Server 5 (in my case anyways) only allowed the "ping" method and all other methods were disallowed. You will either need to update that  block to reflect a comma-delimited list of the methods you want to make accessible via HTTP (white listing) or allow all and deny none (I wouldn't recommend that).

Don't rely on a soft restart of the Adobe/Flash Media Server via the web based Administration Console. This did not work for me. I needed to restart the AMS service from within the Windows Services panel in order for the changes made in the configuration files to take effect.

I hope that this helps!

Rick